# Converting waveform data to visuals?

Tags: javascript, audio, canvas, audiowaveform

I have a decent understanding of what I am doing but am missing a few details so let me break it down.

First I am converting an audio file to waveform data using [audiowaveform](https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform#usage) then on the client it gets converted to a [WaveformData object](https://github.com/bbc/waveform-data.js).

What I understand is that the data contains pairs of min/max [waveform data points interleaved](https://github.com/bbc/audiowaveform/blob/master/doc/DataFormat.md#json-data-format-json)

**Example**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "channels": 2,
  "sample_rate": 48000,
  "samples_per_pixel": 512,
  "bits": 8,
  "length": 3,
  "data": [-65,63,-66,64,-40,41,-39,45,-55,43,-55,44]
}
```

With this understanding if I want to achieve drawing bars [like this](https://motionbox.io/template/podcast-cover-art-template) then I simply take that data and create a bar for every min/max pair, kind of like this.

```
 63  64  41  45  43  44
-65 -66 -40 -39 -55 -55
```

Here is how I am achieving this using the waveform-data.js API. [I also made an interactive Code Sandbox to make it easy to play with](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-field-3vweo?file=/src/App.tsx)

```
const Visualizer: FC<IVisualizer> = ({
  currentTime,
  height,
  width,
}) => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement | null>(null);
  const [waveform, setWaveform] = useState<WaveformData | null>(null);

  // redraw with new time
  const drawCanvas = (waveform: WaveformData) => {
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

      if (ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();

        const channel = waveform.channel(0);
        const centerY = canvas.height / 2;
        const sDelta = 900; // 900s aka 15 min offset
        const sampleDuration = 0.3; // 300ms of data
        const offsetTime = sDelta + currentTime;
        const startIndex = waveform.at_time(offsetTime);
        const endIndex = waveform.at_time(offsetTime + sampleDuration);
        const length = Math.round(canvas.width); // one bar per px can be improved

        // get min/max given a slice of time offset time + sample duration aka 15 min + 300ms
        const maxData = channel.max_array().slice(startIndex, endIndex);
        const minData = channel.min_array().slice(startIndex, endIndex);

        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          ctx.moveTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY); // plot axis in center
          ctx.lineTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY - maxData[i]); // draw upwards from center point given max value

          ctx.moveTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY); // plot axis in center
          ctx.lineTo((i + 1) * 15, centerY - minData[i]); // draw downwards from center point given min value
        }

        ctx.lineWidth = 10;
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
  };

  // currentTime changes at 60fps this effect causes a redraw with new time information
  useEffect(() => {
    if (waveform) {
      drawCanvas(waveform);
    } else {
      console.log("Waveform is missing");
    }
  }, [waveform, currentTime]);

  // get waveform data and convert to WaveformData object on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/motionbox.audiowaveform.dev/0163b1e0-7a3c-11ec-8459-8141f656f7bf"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => WaveformData.create(json))
      .then((waveform) => {
        console.log(`Waveform has ${waveform.channels} channels`);
        console.log(`Waveform has length ${waveform.length} points`);
        setWaveform(waveform);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={canvasRef} width={width} height={height} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**The Problem**

With this code and my lack of understanding here, the x axis aka time moves right to left, I understand it has to do with `currentTime` and how I am redrawing, but I can't wrap my head around why it's doing this, my mental model isn't clear enough. [Here is an example result](https://motionbox-rendered.b-cdn.net/ckyn87s1c1156609jtbg369cqd?t=1642793177388?f=mp4). Again, [this is what I am trying to achieve](https://motionbox.io/template/podcast-cover-art-template).

It seems the way the desired visual works is each frame has a fixed amount of bars representing time of some sort, maybe 200ms (not sure how to determine). Then somehow is mapped to the waveform data in a way that doesn't cause movement on the x axis. I know I am close but missing some details.

Basically `startIndex` and `endIndex` are constantly moving as `currentTime` moves. This formula needs to be changed slightly so that it gets every 200ms at a time, rather than shifting indexes 1ms at a time.

Again here is an [interactive sandbox -- I enjoyed making it](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-field-3vweo?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: This sounds like a job for [p5 js](https://p5js.org/). Have you checked it out?

Comment: frequency graph instead of waveform?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API#creating_a_frequency_bar_graph

Comment: I am trying to avoid using `decodeAudioData` as it crashes the browser on larger files. Maybe it's possible, I used the web audio API in my old implementation. The bottleneck was the decoding part, maybe there is a way to skip it since I am decoding server side. Also want more frame control over the drawings, so I would need to use `bufferSourceNode` which requires an `AudioBuffer`

Comment: Ok I learned there is a difference between waveform and spectrum https://www.google.com/search?q=spectrum+vs+waveform&rlz=1CDGOYI_enUS972US972&oq=spectrum+vs+wav&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i512j0i22i30.6860j0j7&hl=en-US&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8 maybe it’s possible to convert the data to spectrum data

Comment: You can convert between time and frequency domains with a fourier transform. There is probably several good libs for doing it. If you only need real values you can look for an implementation using the cosine transform.

Comment: npm fft packages comparison here: https://github.com/scijs/fourier-transform/blob/HEAD/benchmark.md

Comment: Cool I am looking into them. Also trying out modifying the array buffer so that `decodeAudioData` doesn't need the entire array buffer. A solution is around the corner, going to keep hacking.

Comment: If it turns out that the number crunching is too slow, you can probabily do with fairly large bin sizes, since your bars are pretty wide (low frequency resolution). And perhaps lower the refresh rate from 60 fps, or perhaps take the job of updating the canvas away from reacts whole render-process? Good luck, it looks very cool!